# Python if statement syntax error problems

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I don't get some syntax for **`if`** statements in python:

```
>> z=[0 if all([2<3,6<7]) else sth]    #Correct
>>
>> z=[0 if all([2<3,6<7])]             #Wrong
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    z=[0 if all([2<3,6<7])]
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>
```

I don't know this syntax and difference between `Correct` line and `Wrong` line?

Comment: To clarify, suppose that the `all` condition was false.  What value would you want assigned to `z`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the `A if condition else B` syntax in the correct one, which returns an *expression* to be assigned to your `z` variable

In the wrong one you're omitting the `else` clause, so Python can't guess what to put in case your condition `all([2<3,6<7])` is not met, which isn't workable so it's not allowed

if you only want to set a value in that case then:

```
if <condition>:
   z = [0]
```

or if you like one-liners: `if <condition>: z = [0]`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot skip `else` while using this syntax. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Python

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions doesn't work that way, you thought it like;

```
def sm():
    if somethingelse:
        return something
    return something1
```

Probably? In this case we dont have to write `else` because if `if` statement works, function is done by `return something`. But in list comprehensions it's not like that. As you know you don't have to write `else` in `lambda` too because lambda is a function too, like the example above.